# Я две хурмы зараз / за раз съел

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Я две хурмы зараз / за раз съел.

> Я зараз / за раз пять кругов пробежал.

> Она зараз / за раз выкурила пять сигарет.

> Он её зараз / за раз влюбил в себя.

Comment: Леопольд-мэтр зачем задавать вопросы, на которые вы и сами знаете ответ?

Comment: Серж,  ответ здесь неочевиден. Приходится выбирать, а значения похожи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Я две хурмы **зараз** (= сразу, **за один прием**) съел.*

*Я **зараз** (= сразу, **без остановки**) пять кругов пробежал.*  Возможно раздельно: ***за (один) раз.***

*Она **зараз** (= подряд, **в один прием**) выкурила пять сигарет.*  Возможно раздельно: ***за (один) раз.***

*Он её **зараз** (= быстро, **мигом**) влюбил в себя.*

**Орфографический словарь:**

**зараз**, нареч. (сейчас, сию минуту, обл.)

**зараз**, нареч. (сразу, **за один прием**)

**Большой толковый словарь**

**ЗАРАЗ**, нареч. 1. Разг. **За один приём, сразу.** Выпить з. два стакана чаю. **Пройти з. всё расстояние.** З. прочесть статью в газете. 2. Нар.-разг. Тотчас же, сию минуту. З. чайник согреем.

**СРАЗУ**, нареч. 1. **В один приём; одним разом.** Съел все с. * Москва не сразу строилась (Посл.). // Вместе, одновременно. Говорили все с. В его голосе прозвучали с. гнев и удивление. С. купить несколько платьев. 2. **В тот же момент**; немедленно. С. же сообразил. Узнать кого-л. не с. Отвечайте с., не раздумывая. С. по приезде на дачу отправились в лес. С., как садится солнце, становится холодно. // Минуя предшествующие стадии, немедленно, прямо. Начать изучение языка с. с разговорной речи. 3. **Рядом,** в непосредственной близости от чего-л. С. за домом начинается лес.

Сравнить (возможные вариант):

Майя Кучерская. Тетя Мотя // «Знамя», 2012
Еще одна рюмашка, оставалось уже совсем немного, во как цельную бутылочку **за раз**, а что?

Виктор Чигир. Марцелл // «Дальний Восток», 2019
Но упражнения на брусьях давались с трудом (всего три-четыре подъема **за раз**), и брусья я вскоре забросил.

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно тут недостаточно оснований для слитного написания. Так что за_раз. Зараз может употребляться в обстоятельствах, не являющихся самодостаточной смысловой фразой.

Кроме того "съел обе хурмы зараз" - было бы лучше и скорее всего можно было бы зараз, а "две хурмы" - скорее всего за_раз. Но контекста не достаточно.

> И получимши билетик, он его тотчас разменял, выпил зараз два стаканчика, сдачу взял и пошел, а Митрея я с ним в тот час не видал. Достоевский.

Зараз, потому что тотчас, потому что действия сделаны почти одновременно без пауз - получимши(уже получается свойство, а не действие), тотчас разменял, выпил зараз, сдачу(акцент на предмете, а не на действии) взял и пошёл~взямши сдачу пошёл. То есть через причастные обороты.

Я, съевши две хурмы зараз... - уже требует продолжения, а тут смысловая фраза оборвана на заразе, так что нет, не достаточно, собственно действия не хватает. Зараз употребляется в качестве обстоятельства, а не основного действия, должен быть дополнительный контекст.

*— Таким образом, у вас, значит, зараз было две жены? Лесков* - две жены = двоеженец. Таким образом - союз и логический вывод из предыдущего посыла.

*Надо лить туда воду, потому что самка кладет до 300 яичек зараз, из которых через месяц являются личинки.Максимос* - язык не поворачивается сказать "до трех сотен", и опять же есть основное действие: надо налить воду - являются личинки, - остальное это обстоятельство.

Зараз пробежал пять кругов - может быть, но только в качестве обстоятельства, а не как основная фраза фраза. Возможно: **а я** зараз пробежал... - союз может указывать на продолжение какого-то действия в соседней фразе.

Он её зараз влюбил в себя... - тоже рвано, и сомнительно звучит, что он влюбил, если бы она влюбила - то да, а он влюбил - тоже не понятно.